# Communication two hosts have same ip on different network interface

Tags: windows, networking, windows-networking

I'v two identical network devices that have hardcoded same ip address but different mac adressess. Both of them are connected to different nic on my windows machine. Both of them listen same udp port, accept udp messages only from preconfigured source address and reply to preconfigured destination ip:port address.
How can i manage this devices simultaneously? If it possible to handle this on linux with like that iptables or ip routing?

I'v tried to use raw sockets to build and send ethernet packet. For this i assign different ip address to each nic. And give predefined ip address on ethernet packet when sending it with raw socket. But packet didn't send. It' seems windows blocking the ip packet if the source ip is not real.
I'v also tried build and send raw udp-ip-ethernet packet with npcap. But it didn't work also.

Answer (score 1):

I did it on both windows and linux by ip forwarding. The trick is map the ip addresses to some other ip address.

For example the network devices real ip address would be `10.10.1.20/24` and reply address would be `10.10.1.10/24`. We decide to some other ip address for each network device and send packets to this ip. For example the application which want to communicate to first device on interface-1 would send udp packets to destination address `10.20.1.20` and would send to destination address `10.20.2.20` for communicate to second device on interface-2. And after that we need to something like that collect all packets, rewrite the destination and source ip address to real ip address and finalliy send it from corresponding nic.
I made it with `iptables` and `ebtables` on linux.

But windows doesn't has iptables. So i made custom application using raw socket to make do it. The application simply catch the ip pakets that has destination address `10.20.1.20` and buil a new eth packet by change the source address to `10.10.1.10` and destination ip addresses to `10.10.1.20` and send it to corresponding nic-1. And do something for packets the destination address is `10.10.2.20` and send it to nic-2.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize or not that this is exactly what I told you that you had to do.  There just wasn't enough detail in your post to tell you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give two network devices the same IP address.  That's akin to having two houses with the exact same postal mailing address and expecting mail to be delivered to the correct house.  I think you need to start with what are you trying to do.  If I had to guess, you want to have two NICs, so one isn't a single failure point?  If so, what you are looking for in Windows is NIC Teaming.  In Windows server, you enable this in server manager, in Windows 10/11 via PowerShell.  Here is a link explaining both: [https://woshub.com/configure-nic-teaming-windows/](https://woshub.com/configure-nic-teaming-windows/#h2_3)

Comment: I don't want to give two network devices the same IP address. I want to simply communicate with two network devices. But devices have same IP address and i can't change it. Actually, the number of devices i want to communicate is more then two and all of them have same IP address.

Comment: You don't want to give two devices the same IP address, but you are stating that both devices have the same IP address (more than that even).  It is not possible for them to communicate if they have the same IP address and they are on the same network.  You'd have to segment the networks and then join them together via a router (or other layer 3 capable device or app) and let them communicate that way. You'd need to do this for every device in this scenario.  Without enough information on why both devices have the same IP address and why you haven't changed that, this cannot be answered as is.